# Kotlin async speed test results evaluation

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I did some tests which compare speed of using async as a method of deferring results and CompletableDeferred with combination of Job or startCoroutine to do the same job. 
In summary there are 3 use cases:

- async with default type of start (right away) [**async**]
- CompletableDeferred + launch (basically Job)  [**cdl**]
- CompletableDeferred + startCoroutine          [**ccdl**]

results are presented here:
[image: test results]

In short every iteration of each use case test generates 10000 of async / cdl / ccdl requests and waits for them to complete. This is repeated 225 times with 25 times as a warmUp (not included in results) and data points are collected over 100 iteration of process above (as min, max, avg).

here is a code:

```
import com.source.log.log
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
import kotlin.coroutines.startCoroutine
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

/**
 * @project Bricks
 * @author SourceOne on 28.11.2019
 */

/*I know that there are better ways to benchmark speed
* but given the produced results this method is fine enough
* */
fun benchmark(warmUp: Int, repeat: Int, action: suspend () -> Unit): Pair<List<Long>, List<Long>> {
    val warmUpResults = List(warmUp) {
        measureNanoTime {
            runBlocking {
                action()
            }
        }
    }

    val benchmarkResults = List(repeat) {
        measureNanoTime {
            runBlocking {
                action()
            }
        }
    }

    return warmUpResults to benchmarkResults
}


/* find way to cancel startedCoroutine when deferred is
*  canceled (currently you have to cancel whole context)
* */
fun <T> CoroutineScope.completable(provider: suspend () -> T): Deferred<T> {
    return CompletableDeferred<T>().also { completable ->
        provider.startCoroutine(
            Continuation(coroutineContext) { result ->
                completable.completeWith(result)
            }
        )
    }
}

suspend fun calculateAsyncStep() = coroutineScope {
    val list = List(10000) {
        async { "i'm a robot" }
    }

    awaitAll(*list.toTypedArray())
}



suspend fun calculateCDLStep() = coroutineScope {
    val list = List(10000) {
        CompletableDeferred<String>().also {
            launch {
                it.complete("i'm a robot")
            }
        }
    }

    awaitAll(*list.toTypedArray())
}



suspend fun calculateCCDLStep() = coroutineScope {
    val list = List(10000) {
        completable { "i'm a robot" }
    }

    awaitAll(*list.toTypedArray())
}


fun main() {
    val labels = listOf("async", "cdl", "ccdl")
    val collectedResults = listOf(
        mutableListOf<Pair<List<Long>, List<Long>>>(),
        mutableListOf(),
        mutableListOf()
    )

    "stabilizing runs".log()
    repeat(2) {
        println("async $it")
        benchmark(warmUp = 25, repeat = 200) {
            calculateAsyncStep()
        }

        println("CDL $it")
        benchmark(warmUp = 25, repeat = 200) {
            calculateCDLStep()
        }

        println("CCDL $it")
        benchmark(warmUp = 25, repeat = 200) {
            calculateCCDLStep()
        }
    }

    "\n#Benchmark start".log()
    val benchmarkTime = measureTimeMillis {
        repeat(100) {
            println("async $it")
            collectedResults[0] += benchmark(warmUp = 25, repeat = 200) {
                calculateAsyncStep()
            }

            println("CDL $it")
            collectedResults[1] += benchmark(warmUp = 25, repeat = 200) {
                calculateCDLStep()
            }

            println("CCDL $it")
            collectedResults[2] += benchmark(warmUp = 25, repeat = 200) {
                calculateCCDLStep()
            }
        }
    }

    "\n#Benchmark completed in ${benchmarkTime}ms".log()
    "#Benchmark results:".log()

    val minMaxAvg = collectedResults.map { stageResults ->
        stageResults.map { (_, benchmark) ->
            arrayOf(
                benchmark.minBy { it }!!, benchmark.maxBy { it }!!, benchmark.average().toLong()
            )
        }
    }

    minMaxAvg.forEachIndexed { index, list ->
        "results for: ${labels[index]} [min, max, avg]".log()
        list.forEach { results ->
            "${results[0]}\t${results[1]}\t${results[2]}".log()
        }
    }
}
```

There is no surprise that the first two use cases (async and cdl) are very close to each other and async is always better (because you don't have the overhead of creating job to complete deferred object) but comparing async vs CompletableDeferred + startCoroutine there is a huge gap between them (almost 2 times) in favor of the last one. Why there is such a big difference and if anyone knows, why shouldn't we just be using CompletableDeferred + startCoroutine wrapper (like `completable()` here) instead of async?

Addition1:
Here is a sample for 1000 points:
[image]
There are constant spikes in async and cdl results and some in ccdl (maybe gc?) but still there is far less with ccdl. I will rerun these tests with changed order of tests interleaving but it seems that it's related to something under the coroutines machinery.

Edit1:

I've accepted Marko Topolnik answer, but in addition to it, you still can use this 'as he called' bare launch method if you await for the result within the scope you have launched it.

In example if you will launch few deffered coroutines (async) and at the end of that scope you will await them all then the ccdl method will work as expected (at least from what i've seen in my tests).

Comment: also there is a very interesting thing about the max chart where async and cdl have performance hits but CD+startCoroutine doesn't - need more points though, to conclude anything, so i will repeat this tests with 1000 and maybe 10000 points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `launch` and `async` are built as a layer on top of the low-level primitive `createCoroutineUnintercepted()`, whereas `startCoroutine` is practically a direct call into it, there aren't any surprises in your benchmark results.

> why shouldn't we just be using `CompletableDeferred` + `startCoroutine` wrapper (like `completable()` here) instead of `async`?

A comment in your code already hints to the answer:

```
/*
 * find way to cancel startedCoroutine when deferred is
 * canceled (currently you have to cancel whole context)
 */
```

The layer you short-circuited with `startCoroutine` is precisely the layer that handles things as cancellation, coroutine hierarchy, exception handling and propagation, and so on.

Here's a simple example that shows you one of the things that break when you replace `launch` with a bare coroutine:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    bareLaunch {
        try {
            delay(1000)
            println("Coroutine done")
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            println("Coroutine cancelled, the exception is: $e")
        }
    }
    delay(10)
}

fun CoroutineScope.bareLaunch(block: suspend () -> Unit) =
        block.startCoroutine(Continuation(coroutineContext) { Unit })

fun <T> CoroutineScope.bareAsync(block: suspend () -> T) =
        CompletableDeferred<T>().also { deferred ->
            block.startCoroutine(Continuation(coroutineContext) { result ->
                result.exceptionOrNull()?.also {
                    deferred.completeExceptionally(it)
                } ?: run {
                    deferred.complete(result.getOrThrow())
                }
            })
        }
```

When you run this, you'll see the bare coroutine got cancelled after 10 milliseconds. The `runBlocking` builder didn't realize it had to wait for it to complete. If you replace `bareLaunch {` with `launch {`, you'll restore the designed behavior where the child coroutine completes normally. The same thing happens with `bareAsync`.

Comment: i did actually tested it today and cancelling on both scope of CompletableDeferred and it's object will cancel the job exactly the same way like async would do. But maybe i got sth wrong. Could you provide me an example where this wrapper will fail in different way than async ?

Comment: also here is a gist for the test i tried, maybe there is something wrong with them https://gist.github.com/krzysiek-zgondek/24d6ad7a9f04f62a9feff9991ee14027

Comment: One thing you can't do with the bare coroutine is this: `val job = async { delay(1000) } as Job; job.cancel()`. You get no handle to the coroutine at all.